# HOWTO transform a tuple of functions into a function that emits a tuple

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tuples

Given that I have a tuple of functions with the same input but different outputs:

```
(A -> B, A -> C, A -> D)
```

How do I convert this into a function that returns a tuple of the respective outputs:

```
A -> (B,C,D)
```

Is there a generic solution to this problem and does it have a name? Code examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You just have to unpack the tuple and apply each function in it to the same input.

```
hoistTup :: (a -> b, a -> c, a -> d) -> (a -> (b, c, d))
hoistTup (f, g, h) x = (f x, g x, h x)
```

Comment: BTW Is the general term for this operation "hoisting" ?

Comment: `hoist` is one of those words that means all sorts of things. I just used it here because I couldn't think of a better one

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if there was a catalog of functional design patterns that used consistent terminology for this stuff.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: If you look at it sideways, you see something resembling a sequencing operation in the function monad. Supposing you had a homogeneous list of functions `[a -> b]` (rather than a heterogeneous tuple) then you get [`sequenceA :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequenceA) for free.

Comment: Somewhat tongue-in-cheek: One of the functional design patterns relevant here is "Don't use tuples"

Comment: You can surely write something like this using generics. I can't promise you'll like it though.

Comment: @yatima2975 You mentioned "Don't use tuples", could you justify your comment? If there is good reason to use some other way of solving this problem I would like to know.

Comment: @murungu, how did you get yourself into this situation to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

`Control.Arrow.(&&&)` does this for pairs of functions, but it's not immediately extensible to larger tuples.

```
>>> (negate &&& (+1)) 3
(-3,4)
>>> (negate &&& (+1) &&& (+2)) 3
(-3,(4,5))
```

Using *lists* of functions, you can just use `<*>` (after wrapping the input in a list as well):

```
>>> [negate, (+1), (+2)] <*> [3]
[-3, 4, 5]
```